# JqueryUI autocomplete in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, jquery-ui

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#auto').autocomplete( source: "main/search" )
```

the code beyond set up the autocomplete env,'#auto' is an input filed.

In my main controller I got the search action

```
def search
  @user = User.find_by_name 'castiel'
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @user.to_json(:only => :name) }
  end
end
```

everything seems working perfectly fine.When I type in a char,let's say a "c",so the ajax request was sent and received the json data.

In firebug, it shows the ajax request successfully get the json data below

```
{"name":"castiel"}
```

so far so good,but the json data's type is not the kind that autocomplete demanded.It demands that json data is like below.

```
{"id":"castiel", "label":"castiel", "value":"castiel"}
```

So here is problem,how to modify the josn data to the kind that I wanted.

Comment: can you show us your erb file?  if i remember well, there is a div called autocomplete that is suppose to appear when the autocomplete get the response.  You have to write a small erb.html to handle the response of your controller.  I did the exact same thing a year ago.. but i cant access my code now...

Comment: thank you for your information,I just updated my question.new issue just came out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the success function, you need to return something like

```
.autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response){
        $.ajax({
            url: "main/search",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                style: "full",
                maxRows: 12,
                term: request.term
            },success: function( data ) {
                    response( $.map( data, function( user ) {
                        return {
                            label: user.name,
                            value: user.id
                        }
                    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails allows you to serve JSON in any structure from your controller. When using the jQuery autocomplete helper, you serve JSON back in the format needed by using the autocomplete library method json_for_autocomplete as follows:

```
# app/controllers/example_controller.rb

def autocomplete_example
  items = Example.where(...)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json do
      render :json => json_for_autocomplete(items, 'name', [])
    end
  end
end
```

The first argument to json_for_autocomplete is your collection of objects to return. The second is the method to call on those objects to define the values in the JSON hash. The final argument is for any extra options, which can be found at:

https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/blob/master/lib/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/autocomplete.rb